# Failure to send data back to a previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using onActivityResult to get the data from the previous intent and it is work fine.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case (11): {
            newPosition = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

But the issue is occur when I use action bar back button to go back to the previous intent. It is giving this following error:

```
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=11, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.cogneti/com.cogneti.ui.recall.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2726)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2769)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1023)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.cogneti.ui.recall.TestActivity.onActivityResult(TestActivity.java:221)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4483)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2722)
01-10 15:33:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  ... 11 more
```

It is working fine when I use default back button.

I setresult in onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("position", selectedPosition);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    };
```

Comment: And where is your code for set Result to Intent in Previous Activity??

Comment: wait i am edit the question for that

Comment: guess your data is null. Are you sure you setResult in your previous activity with the intentbundle?

Comment: yes i am set it in onBackPressed() method

Comment: It is not working only when i use the action bar back button as I say.

Comment: Have you setResult in onClick of the action bar backbutton?

Comment: no I dont know about that. Can you please specify @user936414

Comment: is it the home button(in action bar) press or an explicit back button ?

Comment: ok i am just trying that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

Make a Function of result data with code.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("position", selectedPosition);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

And call this function from `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` of Previous Activity.

Actually I think When you press Back from Action Bar   `public void onBackPressed()` is not called, so you have to call this code in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` of activity.

**Update:**

I think this will called when you press back on Action Bar

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    // Here write your set Result on Intent code..          
    finish();
    return true;
}
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: the first one is not work for me i will try for the second one